# When to create a function rather than a procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have many `stored procedures` that are in production but no `functions`.

Here in MSDN is the definition of [**`CREATE FUNCTION`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx). It says the following:

> Creates a user-defined function in SQL Server 2012. A user-defined
>   function is a Transact-SQL or common language runtime (CLR) routine
>   that accepts parameters, performs an action, such as a complex
>   calculation, and returns the result of that action as a value. The
>   return value can either be a scalar (single) value or a table. Use
>   this statement to create a reusable routine that can be used in these
>   ways:

My stored procedures already seem to achieve all of the above.

What is a definite situation when one chooses a `function` rather than a `stored procedure`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to use the result integrated as part of a larger query.

e.g. you can `join` or `cross apply` table valued functions and you can evaluate a Scalar UDF for each row in a result (with care as this can have performance implications).

For stored procedures you would need to execute them and capture the result into a temporary table etc to be able to join on it in a wider query and would require cursors or similar to simulate the Scalar UDF behaviour and execute it for each row.